# Adding more resources for an in house app service when started?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, service, resource-management

background:
   Have a in house app that does heavy video encoding. The service fails from time to time as you can imagine.
I have a windows task that will restart the service every 4 hours. However when the task runs; the application service (heavy video encoding app) being restarted fails. Thus giving an error and a manual start becomes required.
On second try the service starts like it should until it fails again.

Question:
   I would like to find a way to add more resources (memory,CPU) on start up to allow the service to start correctly without going back to the developers and getting a rewrite.
   Is there a way to test this in case I have to take it to the developers and prove my point?

Comment: is this a dedicated VM you are trying to restart or a service?  A service or process will take whatever resources it's allowed to take as requested.  The only way to restrict a process is with FSRM

Comment: Yes it is a dedicated VM. however there is 4 of them behind a load balancer. I will have a look at FSRM. Thanks,

Comment: if it's a dedicated vm then you are already using all the resources in the VM

Comment: agreed. the OS is using the resources available. However I am trying to get a in house or 3rd party windows service more resources. so the VM layer would not matter other than the OS level Virtual hardware.  I was hoping to say "mycrappyApp" windows service gets 60% cpu and 80% memory on startup.  This is most likely a push to the developer I suppose. Thank you @JimB

Comment: Probably, reducing the available resources is an admin issue, FSRM is that constraint, but if its not calling for it at all- that's a dev issue.